# How to map 2 char* arrays directly into std::map<std::string,std::string>

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, char

I have 2 char arrays like "const char *arr1[ArrSize] = {"Blah1", "Wibble1", "Shrug1"};".
For putting them into a vector I found a nice quick solution:

```
void fillVecTest()
{
    const int ArrSize = 3;
    const char *arr1[ArrSize] = {"Blah1", "Wibble1", "Shrug1"};
    const char *arr2[ArrSize] = {"Blah2", "Wibble2", "Shrug2"};
    std::vector<std::string> vec1(arr1, arr1+ArrSize);
    std::vector<std::string> vec2(arr2, arr2+ArrSize);
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator l_It1Vec1;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator l_It = vec1.end();
    l_It = find(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::string("Blah1"));
    if(l_It != vec1.end())
    {
      size_t l_pos = l_It - vec1.begin();
      printf("found %s, pos=%u val: %s\n", l_It->c_str(),l_pos, vec2[l_pos].c_str());
    }
 }
```

Now I thought it should be also possible to put both directly into a map as arr1 is the key and arr2 is the value. I tried some ways but I didn't succeed.

```
void fillMapTest()
{
    const int ArrSize = 3;
    const char *arr1[ArrSize] = {"Blah1", "Wibble1", "Shrug1"};
    const char *arr2[ArrSize] = {"Blah2", "Wibble2", "Shrug2"};
    std::map<std::string,std::string> map1;//(pair(arr1,arr1), pair(arr1+ArrSize,arr2+ArrSize));
    std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator l_It1Map1;
    //l_It1Map1 = find(map1.begin(), map1.end(), std::string("Blah1"));
    if(l_It1Map1 != map1.end())
    {
      printf("found key: %s, val: %s\n",l_It1Map1->first.c_str(), l_It1Map1->second.c_str());
    }

}


int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv[]*/)
{
  fillVecTest();
  fillMapTest();
  return 0;
}
```

I think that just the commented lines in function "fillMapTest" would need to be solved.
Constuctor and find don't work like I want.

Please has any STL expert an idea?

Comment: I forgot to say that I use C++98 and I'm looking first for the constructor solution, if there any.
e.g std::map<std::string,std::string> map1(pair(arr1,arr1), pair(arr1+ArrSize,arr2+ArrSize));

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to write this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m {
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" },
};
```

This requires your compiler to support [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (a feature of C++11).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think it's time to assume people have a C++11 compiler (at least C++0x). If they want to support C++03, they should mention it in the question (my personal opinion). Is there a meta discussion about that?

Comment: [Here it is...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112641/when-did-the-c-tag-start-to-imply-c11-by-default)

Comment: C++11 support is still getting phased in. gcc 4.8 was released a couple weeks ago and still doesn't have all the new features. And it still requires you to explicitly request C++11 with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, We're getting pretty close with GCC and Clang's current statuses.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone You are right, but the initializer list is supported very good by all major compilers.

Comment: @leemes, This isn't in MSVC. The library hasn't been updated for the CTP, and only the CTP has initializer lists.

Comment: I brought this up because we just moved from 4.5 to 4.7.3 a month ago (4.8.0 is a tad too new) for our embedded ARMv7m work (which Clang does not support IIRC).

Comment: @chris Didn't know that. In this case I'd recommend to simply say that it's C++11 in the answer. (But this discussion should take place in meta...)

Comment: @leemes, As time goes on, more people are going to use C++11. Might as well get it in our answers now :)

Comment: Are we writing for eternity, or to answer Alf-SW's question? IMHO, this question has two answers, depending on C++11's availability.

Comment: The 2 arr1&2 are given as key/value pair and I would like to use just the map-constructor like I did with vector.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++) {
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> p =
        std::make_pair(std::string(arr1[i]), std::string(arr2[i]));
    m.insert(p);
}
```

---

If you really want to use the map constructor you need an iterator of pairs and the only  way(i know) is to use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >::iterator` but this seems to be an unneeded extra step to get the same result.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > values;

for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++) {
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> p =
        std::make_pair(std::string(arr1[i]), std::string(arr2[i]));
    values.push_back(p);
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> m(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Comment: If you have C++11 handy, you can replace `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` with `auto`. Or, in either C++, you could just write `m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string(arr1[i]), std::string(arr2[i])));`

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Agreed, in c++11 I would use KerrekSB's solution. But nothing in op's code indicates c++11, and I just wanted to be clear for OP what's happening in the code so I added the extra variable `p`.

Comment: I agree in keeping this answer C++03-compatible. So we have a C++11 and a C++03 solution.

Comment: Nice solution and I'll hope it takes me further but the final goal is to get a similar solution just to use the map-constructor like I did with vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++) {
    m.insert(pair<string, string>(arr1[i], arr2[i]));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but I still hope to find a similar solution just to use the map-constructor like I did with vector.

Comment: Now I had time to try it, but get an compile error.
error C2665: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types